# unity system fonts in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, fonts, system-font

I want to use android system font to show Chinese text.
I use

```
var fonts = Font.GetOSInstalledFontNames();
```

to log what fonts are in device. I find this `Noto Sans CJK TC`. 
But I called

```
font = (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "NotoSansTC-Black.ttf");
```

It always shows `The resource NotoSansTC-Black.ttf could not be loaded from the resource file!`
How can I use this font in android device.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [`Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Font.GetOSInstalledFontNames.html)

```
font = Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont("NotoSansTC-Black", 12);
```